# ffplay - Two videos (.mp4), one display screen and just a few seconds to display them together

Tags: video, ffmpeg, split-screen

I have two videos (.mp4), one display screen and just a few seconds to display them together.

I am able to displayed them together on a split screen via ffmpeg and then opening the output file. The problem is that it takes a long time (3 minutes).

Here is the Code: (first code)

```
$ ffmpeg -i _20180114094126_flightvideo_cam1.mp4 -i _20180114094126_flightvideo_cam2.mp4 -filter_complex " [0:v]crop=1280:360:0:0[v0];[1:v]scale=1280:-1,crop=1280:360:0:0[v1]; [v0] [v1]vstack[v]" -map [v] -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast 6000screen_take1.mkv
```

On the other hand, when using ffplay I am able to modify one video at the time and play it right away:

```
$ ffplay -i _20180114094126_flightvideo_cam1.mp4 -vf scale=425:-2
```

How can I have the same outcome as the first code above, but display it on my screen right away(without waiting for the output file to be created, 3 minutes in this case)?

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i 
         "movie=20180114094126_flightvideo_cam1.mp4,crop=1280:360:0:0[v0];
          movie=_20180114094126_flightvideo_cam2.mp4,scale=1280:-1,crop=1280:360:0:0[v1];
         [v0][v1]vstack"
```